# AS3 drag n drop to one single object

Tags: actionscript-3

(I am not good in AS so please be nice :) )

I am working on  simple flash game in which there r 8 small circles out side of one big circle. i want to drag this 8 small circle one by one to the big circle.

Basically 1 plate with their food items.Draging their food items to he plate. i hope this would give you a better idea.
I have goggled it the same thing but could not get what i want, :(

Please suggest me the script or method.

If there are any links or tuts please let me know i would really appreciate.

Thanks,

Kunal(Web - Designer)

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested and works. The class **DummyCircle** just draws a centered circle to its graphics object when instantiated.

```
private var plate:Sprite;
private var stage:Stage;

public function execute(stage:Stage):void 
{
    this.stage = stage;
    // number of pieces around the centered plate
    const numPieces:int = 8;
    const plateRadius:int = 50;
    plate = new DummyCircle(plateRadius);
    // center plate on the stage
    plate.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    plate.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    stage.addChild(plate);
    // for each piece to be created
    for (var i:int = 0; i < numPieces; i++) {
        // instantiate the appropriate sprite, here with a radius argument
        var piece:Sprite = new DummyCircle(plateRadius / numPieces);
        // add event listener for dragging
        piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseListener);
        piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseListener);
        // pieces are in the top left corner of the stage, plate is centered
        piece.x = 0;
        piece.y = 0;
        // a transformation matrix is used for positioning the pieces
        // get the current matrix
        var pieceMatrix:Matrix = piece.transform.matrix;
        // move a bit more than the plate radius on the y axis
        pieceMatrix.translate(0, -plateRadius * 1.5);
        // rotate around the origin
        pieceMatrix.rotate(i * (2 * Math.PI / numPieces));
        // move again, this time to our plate
        pieceMatrix.translate(plate.x, plate.y);
        // apply the matrix
        piece.transform.matrix = pieceMatrix;
        stage.addChild(piece);
    }
}

private function mouseListener(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if (e.target is Sprite) {
        var target:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
        if (e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP) {
            target.stopDrag();
            if (target.hitTestObject(plate)) {
                stage.removeChild(target);
            }
        }
        else if (e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN) {
            target.startDrag();
        }
    }
}
```